# Get the argument types of a C99 variadic function

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Consider the following code:

```
template <class... Args>
struct function_arguments
{
    using tuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <class>
struct function_traits
: function_arguments<>
{};

template <class R, class... Args>
struct type<R(Args...)>
: function_arguments<Args...>
{};

template <class R, class... Args>
struct type<R(Args... ...)>
: function_arguments<Args...>
{};
```

and the following function declarations:

```
int f(int x, int y, int z);
int g(int x, int y, int z, ...);
```

Without problem `function_traits<decltype(f())>::tuple` will return a tuple with all the argument types in it. Is there a way to do the same thing for a C99 variadic function (extracting Args... + C99 variadic types and put everything together in a tuple)? If so, how?c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you may add a tag for ellipsis and do

```
struct ellipis_tag {};

template <class R, class... Args>
struct type<R(Args... ...)>
: function_arguments<Args..., ellipis_tag>
{};
```